# Prove $r_1 = r_2 \Leftarrow\Rightarrow Sr_1 = Sr_2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

With a construction of $\Bbb{R}$, to every real number $r\in\Bbb{R}$, $Sr:= (-\infty, r)\cap\Bbb{Q}$.

$Sr$ is the set of all rational numbers < r.

Prove, rigorously, $r_1 = r_2  \Leftarrow\Rightarrow Sr_1 = Sr_2$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have proved from left to right. I am not sure how to deal with the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bullet \quad r_1=r_2 \Longrightarrow Sr_1=Sr_2$ is true by definition

$\bullet  \quad Sr_1=Sr_2 \Longrightarrow r_1=r_2$ : you can suppose without loss of generality that $r_1 \geq r_2$. If by the absurd you had $r_1>r_2$ then you would have $Sr_1 \backslash Sr_2 = [r1,r2) \cap\mathbb{Q}$ but $[r1,r2) $ is a not empty interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ therefore you could find an element in $Sr_1$ that is not in $Sr_2$ : contradiction. Hence $r_1=r_2$